How to prove that $\Pi_{\substack{1\leq i\leq m}\\{m+1\leq j\leq n}}\dfrac{1}{i-j}=\Pi_{\substack{1\leq i\leq m}\\{m+1\leq j\leq n}}\dfrac{1}{j-i-n}$?
While attempting to prove that the Hodge *-operator an an oriented real inner product vector space is involutive up to sign, I came across the following problem which I needed to complete the proof. The problem is if given any two natural numbers $m,n$ with $m\leq n$, then the following products are equal:
$$\prod_{\substack{1\leq i\leq m}\\{m+1\leq j\leq n}}\dfrac{1}{i-j}=\prod_{\substack{1\leq i\leq m}\\{m+1\leq j\leq n}}\dfrac{1}{j-i-n}.$$
I have no clue how to proceed, any help is appreciated.

Let $$u=m-i+1\quad\text{and}\quad v=n-j+m+1.$$ Then,
$$\prod_{1\le u\le m\atop m+1\le v\le n}\frac1{u-v}=\prod_{1\le i\le m\atop m+1\le j\le n}\frac1{j-i-n}.$$

Wow, you’re so fast. I wonder how do you instantly come up with these substitutions?

I looked for a substitution leaving invariant the two sets ${1,\dots,m}$ and ${m+1,\dots,n}$, and the first one I thought of happened to work.
